# Use prepareForSegue:Sender when switching VC in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I have googled far and wide, but everything is extremely confusing. I need it so when the tab bar gets switched to a different view controller, is there a method that gets called when the view controllers are about to switch, get the destination controller and set some variables to add some annotations to a MKMapView. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation with the delegate methods, I was able to find an answer.

I used the `- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController` method.

This feels like a fairly decent replacement because you can get each controller easily.

**Warning: This method should not be used to handle large blocks of code, but to set up a view controller to run large blocks of code.**

A test implementation:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    FirstViewController *currentController = (FirstViewController *)[tabBarController selectedViewController];
    SecondViewController *destinationController = (SecondViewController *)viewController;
// If you want, do some code on these here. For more precision, read on.
return YES;
}
```

This can be used with logic to determine whether you should execute some specific code: EX:

```
if ([[tabBarController selectedViewController] class] == [FirstViewController class]) {
    if ([viewController class] == [SecondViewController class]) {

    // It is going from first to second. Do some code here.
    }  
}
```

Also, you have to have set the delegate

```
TabBarController .h

@interface TabBarController : UITabBarController<UITabBarControllerDelegate>
...



TabBarController .m
...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.delegate = self;

}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many options, but one of them is to implement  the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol and then set the class that implements it as the delegate of your `UITabBarController`. The delegate receives a message `- tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`

In that method you can implement the behavior you desire by looking at the last view controller and the next one.  To get access to those view controllers from your delegate, you may need to add them as `weak` properties to your delegate class. You can also access all of your `UITabBarController`'s sub view controllers through its `viewControllers` property which is an array of view controllers.

Comment: So If I get the view controller that was selected, I can set my vars. One question. Is this method called before the viewWill/DidAppear on my map view controller?

Comment: I think so, but you should read the docs and also... when you have questions like this you can always answer them yourself with a couple NSLog()s